# Excel Date Time Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to format a datetime so that Excel can read it. So far, I've been able to convert by separating the date from text to strings, but might there be an easier way to account for "EDT"?

Note that the EDT doesn't matter, as all the times are in "EDT". However, if there is timezone functionality, that would be great.

The string:

```
Wed Jul 01 02:57:58 EDT 2015
```

How I'd like Excel to read it, where the "."s represent text to ignore:

```
ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss ... yyyy
```

Comment: Can you try with zzz in format. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634398.aspx

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam That is a valid argument in the VBA Format Function.  As part of the Excel worksheet numberformat string, it will merely display a string of z's.

Comment: What formula are you using?  What is your problem with it?  There is no time zone functionality in the Excel number format string.  This does exist in VBA, if you really need it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm using the custom time format functionality in the toolbar.

Comment: You wrote that you've been able to convert it.  I've told you there is no TZ function in the number format string.  What, exactly, is your problem?

Comment: If you are trying to "convert" the string using the time format, you can't do that.  The cell format only displays how a value is displayed. It has not effect on how Excel interprets a string.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Just to clarify that there is no functionality like zzz that the other user posted...

Comment: That is what I wrote.

Comment: There is no super easy way to do it using the built in formulas.  Here is a template for one manner of getting there, but it is pretty convoluted and would not scale well:  =DATEVALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3," EDT "," ",1),"Wed ","",1),FIND(":",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3," EDT "," ",1),"Wed ","",1),1)-4)&", "&RIGHT(A3,4)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3," EDT "," ",1),"Wed ","",1),FIND(":",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3," EDT "," ",1),"Wed ","",1),1)-2,8))

Comment: Excel 2013 and US format

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,3)&"1")),MID(A1,9,2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pnuts formula works absolutely. I have couple more ideas which you can give a try,

`=TEXT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"EDT ",""),20),"mm/dd/yyyy")`

This formula converts it to `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

However if you want to include time also, please try the below formula,

`=TEXT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"EDT ",""),20),"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`

You can change the format in `TEXT` function as per your needs. Hope this helps.